# Add tooltip strings from the profile activity page into transifex (or use existing keys)

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, international-sites, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current

> [image]

There are no such strings in the transifex (those new strings started with capital character).

But there are strings, which previously were used, started with lower case like `your overall summary` (key `dd572debc70aea8e93fe699ee125fa6e`), but they are not used anymore.

Same for tooltips on navigation buttons.

> [image]

Could you use the existing strings or add new strings into transifex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those new words were added several days ago into transifex. So now we can translate it.